# Printing out found text in webpage

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What I'd like to do is print the text that contains what I'm searching for (examples below code). Currently I'm trying to do this with HtmlAgilityPack

```
foreach(HtmlNode found in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., Test123')]]"))
{
      //print the text
}
```

I know when it finds the text (in this case `Test123`), there'll be plenty of text around it. Simply printing `Test123` would be pointless. If possible, I'd like to print the raw text that contains `Test123`. Here's an example...
`<input name="something" value="aaaTest1234" />`
and
`<body>bbbTest12345</body>`
...would print `aaaTest1234` and `bbbTest12345` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For "input name="something" value="aaaTest1234"" all of the contents within(including) '<>' would be returned as 'HtmlNode found', then you should parse the Attributes value of 'found' to get the part you are interested.
While for second one, you need to parse InnerText of body.

Comment: Thank you. So there's no way to do a generic search? I have to do a search for specific cases?

Comment: Or if I have to do it this way, can I at least tell which attribute contains the value I searched for?

Comment: @MichaelBlake, you can try GetAttributeValue(string name, string def);  Check  - http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode/M/GetAttributeValue

Answer (score 0):

How about printing raw HTML of the `HtmlNode` through `OuterHtml` property? :

```
foreach(HtmlNode found in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., Test123')]]"))
{
    //print HTML of the element that contain the text:
    Console.WriteLine(found.OuterHtml);
}
```